# Adding VBS Script To Windows Context Menu

Tags: windows, vbscript, menu

I'm trying to add a vbs script to the Windows context menu. I've found various sites that explain how to modify the registry to do it, and I've done it.

The link comes up when I right-click on the correct file type - but when I try to run it, it comes up with the message that it's not a valid win32 application. It's ignoring the script I added to the registry and for some reason trying to actually run the file.

I've substituted an .exe into the same command, and it runs fine. Is there something I have to do to have it run a .vbs instead of an .exe?

Comment: Try using `wscript.exe "c:\path\to\your\script.vbs" "%1"`.

Comment: Didn't work. Now the error message is "There is no script engine for file extension ".exe".

Comment: Hmm. I just tried it and it worked for me. You're trying to pass a file as a parameter to a VBScript by right-clicking it and choosing a custom context-menu handler that calls your script?

Comment: At the moment I'm not even worrying about the file going in as a parameter - I'm just trying to run a VBScript by right-clicking on a file of a certain type and choosing a custom context-menu handler that calls that script. The Data for the key in regedit is "C:\Program Files\t.vbs". If I change that to some exe - "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\ImagingDevices.exe" for example - it works fine, launching that app. If I run it with the VBScript, I get the error I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Well you should probably add some more detail to your post: a screenshot or registry file showing the changes you made, your VBScript, what O/S you're on, the name file you're right-clicking, etc.

Comment: You're right - my apologies

Comment: In an effort to provide a better question, including screenshots, and to properly document the error messages, I went back and tried the first suggested solution (wscript.exe "c:\program files\t.vbs" "%1") in order to get the correct error message. And it worked. So I figure I'm just an idiot who didn't do it right the first time. Thanks for your help.